# Split Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin Output into Multiple Files

Tags: javascript, webpack

I am using Webpack to bundle my clientside modules and would like to take advantage of parallel asset downloading. I would like html somewhat like this:

```
<script src="vendor/react.js">
<script src="vendor/underscore.js">
<script src="build/bundle.js">
```

Where bundle.js contains:

```
var React = require('react');
var _ = require('underscore');
```

Note that vendor/react.js and vendor/underscore.js would also be bundled by Webpack.

I know that the Webpack CommonsChunkPlugin can extract *all* the vendor modules and put them into a single common vendor.js file. Is it possible, though, to split that common output file into two or more output files?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit more digging, I found an answer.

Soundcloud created a webpack plugin specifically for this purpose ([see here](https://github.com/soundcloud/split-by-name-webpack-plugin)) though it lacked support for splitting code in the node_modules folder. [Another plugin](https://github.com/BohdanTkachenko/webpack-split-by-path) based on it solved that problem and was trivial to set up.